# i have a shared folder on a server where i want to create files and subfolders with java?

Tags: java, file-io

i have a shared folder on a server where i want to create files and subfolders with java. The problem is with the permissions. How can i set a user thorugh my code that can create folder in shared drive.

Comment: How is the drive mounted? Is it a samba share? NFS? Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: i am on windows. Its simply a shared folder on the server. I cannot login to server through my username password. But we have a common username password for that server. When i am running my code thorough my login it says access denied. However i am sure if i had some way of setting myself as that common user i would be able to run code through my sytem.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a filesystemfolder, where you have no writepermissions and want your Software to change the permissions? If thats korrect, the answer would be "You can't"

Comment: Is your Software running as a windows service? Is it a network share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run your code as the common user.

```
runas /user:%USER% /savecred /env "CMD /K %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar \"myapp.jar\" %JAVA_ARGS%"
```

To do this, you need to create a user with the same name an password on you development maschine.
That user should be able to write onto your folder.

**EDIT:**
I'm pretty sure, there is no capability build in with Jave to set an Windows ACL with java.io
If your common user as the permissions to change permissions of your created folders and files, you may run `Runtime.exec("some windows commandline code, to change ACL")`

If your common user doesn't have the permission, my answer is "You can't".